# getting this error Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

Tags: php, yii2

Get this error:

> Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

On very start of this code:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\users;

class UserController extends Controller
{
     public function actionIndex()
     {
         echo "working on .....";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You probably have this error because you have a blankspace after `<?php`

```
 <?php
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\users;

class UserController extends Controller
{
     public function actionIndex()
     {
         echo "working on .....";
     }
}
```

Just delete it

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\users;

class UserController extends Controller
{
     public function actionIndex()
     {
         echo "working on .....";
     }
}
```

Comment: Sageth must have meant "before" <?php

Comment: Attention, one may also have these kinds of messages if their file starts with UTF8 BOM. e.g. Ultra-Edit default settings for UTF8 new files... In which case you must remove the BOM. See your editor doco.

Comment: Yes, this was UTF8 encoding problem I have saved with UTF8 and its work for me.

Answer (score -1):

If don't have namespaces also you will get error. to solve this delete current php file and recreate it. It will solve the problem.